# Convert VBA Case Statement to SQL

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have the following `CASE` Statement in VBA that I need to turn into SQL but, I keep receiving syntax errors:

```vb
Case 1
    strsql = strsql & "            ,SUM(IIF(C.PayRate Is Not Null,C.PayRate * S.frtTons,S.freightRate * S.frtTons)) AS [ExtFrt]            "
Case 2
    strsql = strsql & "            ,SUM(IIF(C.PayRate Is Not Null,C.PayRate * S.tonsSold,S.freightRate * S.tonsSold)) AS [ExtFrt]"
Case Else
    strsql = strsql & "            ,SUM(IIF(C.PayRate Is Not Null,C.PayRate * S.frtTons,S.freightRate * S.frtTons)) AS [ExtFrt] "
```

Comment: What's the error message? I don't think your sql is valid btw?

Comment: Could you add the `SELECT CASE` part of the code - can't figure out what `Case 1` and `Case 2` is without it.

Answer (score 0):

Access SQL does not support CASE. Use IIf() or Switch() or Choose().

Consider:

```
Sum(Nz(C.PayRate, S.freightRate) * IIf(something = 2, S.tonsSold, S.frtTons))
```

`Nz()` is actually a VBA function and using in query causes some reduced efficiency. Alternatives:
`IIf(IsNull(C.PayRate), S.freightRate, C.PayRate)`
`IIf(C.PayRate IS NULL, S.freightRate, C.Payrate)`

Equivalents to `Nz()`: SQLServer has `IsNull()`; MySQL has `IfNull()`; both have `Coalesce()`.

If you really want to use CASE in SQLServer or MySQL, consider:

```
Sum(CASE WHEN C.PayRate Is Null THEN S.freightRate ELSE C.PayRate END * CASE WHEN something = 2 THEN S.tonsSold ELSE S.frtTons END)
```

Comment: I am using MSSQL Sever Management Studio. I am trying to convert the initial VBA query that I posted to just a regular SQL Query. I want to know how I can convert that CASE Statement to a regular MS SQL CASE Statement.

Comment: Maybe you should change tag from MS Access to SQLServer. Also, since you don't want vba that tag is really not needed.

Comment: Why complicate with CASE statement? Suggestions not using Nz() function would work in SQLServer. https://www.sqlshack.com/overview-of-sql-iif-statement/#:~:text=SQL%20IIF%20Statement%20overview%201%20Boolean_expression%3A%20The%20first,it%20returns%20value%20specified%20in%20the%20false_value%20parameter Even that VBA is more complicated than need be.